# Passing a parameter by value and returning the same parameter back to calling function

Tags: c

I'm in a C programming class and the teacher said that it is not a good practice to pass a parameter by value to some function and return the modified parameter into the calling function due to *technical reasons*. He did not clarify what would be the technical reasons?

I know what passing a value by a reference means and I know how to use it and I think I know the difference between passing by a value and passing by reference. I just can't get my head around why couldn't I in, some cases, pass a parameter by value from `main` to a function, modify it, and return it back to the `main`.

Here is my program. My teacher said: *"Because `sum` variable in `askDecimals` is a value parameter (passed by a value), it cannot return information to the calling program"*.

I understand, that I have conducted bad practice here by declaring `sum` in the `main` function and passing it by value into `askDecimals`. Instead, I should declare the `sum` variable inside the `askDecimals` function.

But regardless, my teacher's comment at least for me, sounds like you could never pass a value as parameter and return it.

Please correct me in this now, if I have understood the teacher the wrong way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void askName(char *pName) {
    printf("Enter a name, maximum 20 characters: ");
    fgets(pName, 20, stdin);
    pName[strlen(pName)-1] = '\0';
    return;
}

float askDecimals(float sum, int count) {
    float decimal;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
        scanf("%f", &decimal);
        getchar();
        sum = sum + decimal;
    }
    return sum;
}

void printInfo(int count, char *pName, float sum, float avg) {
    printf("You entered the name: %s.\n", pName);
    printf("You entered the number: %d.\n", count);
    printf("The sum of the decimal numbers was: %f.\n", sum);
    printf("The average of the decimal numbers was: %.2f.\n", avg);
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    char name[20];
    int count;
    float sum = 0;
    float avg;
    askName(name);
    do {
        printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &count);
        getchar();
        if (count <= 0) {
            printf("You must enter a positive integer. Please try again.\n");
        }
    } while (count <= 0);

    sum = askDecimals(sum, count);
    avg = sum / count;
    printInfo(count, name, sum, avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *pass a parameter by value to some function and return the modified parameter into the calling function* - it is not totally clear what it means. Please show an example.

Comment: Like `int addFive(int value) { return value + 5; }`?

Comment: *pass a parameter by value to some function and return the modified parameter into the calling function* [`strcat()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.3.1) seems to do exactly that.

Comment: Person best-placed to answer why your teacher thinks that, or what context you are missing, is the teacher.

Comment: @jarmod Unless the teacher is wrong, which is not that uncommon..

Comment: I've been a C programmer for 40 years and have never heard or read of any such restrictions for technical or otherwise reasons. Ask your teacher.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That is exactly what functions are supposed to do... return values based on the input parameters..

Comment: It sounds that what he meant that you simply can't modify the parameter passed by value and expect the change to be visible outside the function. And yes, it has *technical reasons*.

Comment: It seems that receiving a 'simple' parameter by value to return an updated value is a good practice.

But if the parameter is complex like a structure with a size of about more than 3 `int`, it becomes inefficient. Then we can think of receiving a pointer to update it.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I know, but I was hoping that the OP would clarify exactly what sort of function they were asking about. If it is indeed a function like that then there are no "technical reasons" I know of that would cause an issue.

Comment: Hi, I added my program to which he said it. Please look it carefully. I translated it from another language into english quite fast, so there can be some silly variable names etc.

Comment: You asked this question yesterday.

Comment: *Teacher said: "Because sum variable in askDecimals is a value parameter (passed by a value), it cannot return information to the calling program".* He's right.  Calling `askDecimals(sum, count);` doesn't change the value of `sum`.

Comment: Now that you have given a specific example I'd say your teacher is correct. `sum` should be a local variable to the function. In `main` you should have something like `float sum = askDecimals(count);`. I would argue that the function is poorly named since it gives the caller no hint what the return value is.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I agree, it is poorly named. I also agree on that sum should definitely be a local variable. However, I just became confused as he sounded like I couldn't, in general, pass parameter by a value into function in C and return the same parameter. In this context I understand this, but in general I don't.

Comment: *If* you are looking to have your function to accumulate the `sum` with the passed `sum` - then your code is perfectly fine. The only problem is that it is not what you seem to be expecting it to do. So you have a bug, not any other "technical reasons" (well, not exactly a bug, as you are passing it `sum=0`, but it would be if you called this function again in the same manner).

Comment: @EugeneSh. I agree

Comment: So, what would your teacher think about calling a standard library function like, for example `x = sqrt(y);`?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is my program. My teacher said: *Because `sum` variable in `askDecimals` is a value parameter (passed by a value), it cannot return information to the calling program*.

Indeed the `sum` argument variable in the your `askDecimal` function is a local variable that cannot pass anything back to the caller, but your approach returning the value of `sum` for the caller to update its own variable is fine .  It is a very common idiom for functions dealing with linked lists, where the head pointer may need to be updated.

There are alternatives to this approach, which may or may not produce the same result due to floating point arithmetic limited precision:

Passing a pointer to the total:

```
int askDecimals(float *sum, int count) {
    int c, i = 0;
    if (count) {
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            float decimal;
            printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
            if (scanf("%f", &decimal) != 1)
                break;
            *sum += decimal;
        }
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
    }
    return i;  // return the number of values read from `stdin`.
}
```

Change the invocation in `main` to:

```
    count = askDecimals(&sum, count);
    avg = sum / count;
```

Returning the total:

```
float askDecimals(int count) {
    float sum = 0;
    if (count) {
        int c;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            float decimal;
            printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
            if (scanf("%f", &decimal) != 1)
                break;
            sum += decimal;
        }
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            continue;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Change the invocation in `main` to:

```
    sum += askDecimals(count);  // assuming count values are read.
    avg = sum / count;
```